# powershell datatemplate binding syntax

Tags: wpf, powershell, data-binding, itemscontrol

I'm having problems figuring out the syntax for itemscontrol databinding in powershell.  I have a simple WPF script below with 2 examples of itemscontrol with a data template.   The first one (list01) has multiple elements and does not show properly, the 2nd itemscontrol (list02) has only one binding element and works just fine.

I'm looking for the correct syntax to bind objects to the first itemscontrol (list01).

Complete powershell script (:

```
[xml]$xaml = @'

<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" x:Name="MainWindow"
        Title="ItemsControlDataBindingSample" Height="350" Width="300">
<Grid Margin="10">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition MinHeight="20"/>
        <RowDefinition MinHeight="50"/>
        <RowDefinition MinHeight="50"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ItemsControl Name="LIST01" Grid.Row="1">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="5">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                    <ProgressBar Grid.Column="1" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding Completion}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>

    <ItemsControl Name="LIST02" Grid.Row="2">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="5">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Content="{Binding}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>

    </Window>
    '@

#New-Object System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('PresentationFramework')
[void][reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Drawing')

#Read XAML
$Form = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml) )

#Find objects
$MainWindow = $Form.FindName('MainWindow')
$List01 = $Form.FindName('LIST01')
$List02 = $Form.FindName('LIST02')

## this does not work ##
$Source01 = @(
    [ordered]@{ Title=([string]'Complete this WPF tutorial'); Completion=([int]45) },
    [ordered]@{ Title=([string]'Learn C#'); Completion=([int]80) },
    [ordered]@{ Title=([string]'Wash the car'); Completion=([int]25) }
    [ordered]@{ Title=([string]'Make KIDS do homework'); Completion=([int]3) }
);
## this does not work ##
$Source01 = @{ title='test01'; completion=50 }

## this does not work ##
$testArray = @()
$tmpObject = Select-Object -InputObject "" Title,Completion
$tmpObject.Title = 'Complete this WPF tutorial'
$tmpObject.Completion = 45
$testArray += $tmpObject

$List01.ItemsSource = $testArray
#$List01 | gm -type method


## this WORKS ##
$Source02 = @('TEST01','TEST02','TEST03')
$List02.ItemsSource = $Source02

[void]$Form.ShowDialog();
```

This code is based off a very simple C# example:  http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/itemscontrol

However, I'm not sure how that syntax directly transates to powershell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would probably suggest using an MVVM approach. Just set the `DataContext` property of the window and then bind the `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` property to the list you want, e.g. `ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemsListProperty}"`.

A full example of what this could look like (based on the example code you posted above):

```
$xaml = @"
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" x:Name="MainWindow"
        Title="ItemsControlDataBindingSample" Height="350" Width="300">
<Grid Margin="10">

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemsListProperty}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="5">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />

                    <ProgressBar Grid.Column="1" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding Completion}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>

</Grid>
</Window>
"@

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('PresentationFramework')

#Read XAML
$window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Parse($xaml)

$viewModel = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    MyItemsListProperty = @(    
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{ 
            Title='Complete this WPF tutorial'
            Completion=45.0 
        };    
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{ 
            Title='Learn C#'
            Completion=80.0 
        };    
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{ 
            Title='Wash the car'
            Completion=25.0
        };    
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{ 
            Title='Make KIDS do homework'
            Completion=3.0 
        };
    )
};

$window.DataContext = $viewModel

$window.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Is there something else I have to declare in my code?  I'm getting this binding error:

Exception calling "Parse" with "1" argument(s): "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."
+ $window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Parse($xaml)
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : XamlParseException
 
The property 'DataContext' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
+ $window.DataContext = $viewModel
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) []
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

Comment: The `Parse` error is the only interesting error, since the other follows from not being able to parse. Are you sure you copied the text entirely correct? I have now tried running the above code on four different machines with three different OS's (Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows Server 2012) and also different PowerShell versions (v2 and v4). On all those attempts it has worked well (just as long as I ensure I start the powershell session with the STA flag, but missing that wouldn't give the error message you mention).

Comment: no - sorry ... ran out of characters.  There were 3 separate errors ... i'll re-post the full content: 

Exception calling "Parse" with "1" argument(s): "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, 
position 1."
At line:30 char:1
+ $window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Parse($xaml)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : XamlParseException

Comment: <ERROR #2>

The property 'DataContext' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and 
can be set.
At line:53 char:1
+ $window.DataContext = $viewModel
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

Comment: <ERROR #3>

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:55 char:1
+ $window.ShowDialog()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Comment: Missed your comment about it working on a number of diff machines --- This was tried on a windows 8.1 Ent. machine using PS4.0 ... i'll try on some others and see if i get the same error ... thanks for your help

Comment: WORKS ...  something up with my local machine then ..  there is almost NOTHING on the web showing actual examples of powersehll with XAML, itemscontrol and datatemplates - or viewmodel stuff.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: The other errors are still direct results of failing to Parse the code (therefore the `$window` object is null, which causes the other errors). Thus the only interesting error is the Parse error. Don't know the reason for it though, it was even copied from your code and then altered. Glad you got it working! Now there is at least one more sample of it on the web. :)

Comment: If you've got more examples of this posted elsewhere, I'd love to see them =) ---- thanks again.